# How to pass the index of an element whenever the oninput event occurs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I'm trying to repeat an object using `ng-repeat` Now, whenever my div is repeated with the object which I get from the `ng-repeat` I also want to set the index value for every object

Suppose if I my div is repeated 10 times i.e if I get 10 Objects every object should have an index value.

For example the first object should have index value of 1, second will have index of 2 and so on.

To do this I binded $index in the id of my div Take a look at the code

```
<div ng-repeat="myObject in object" id="{{ $index }}">
</div>
```

Now, I have also used datalists in my div to achieve autocomplete feature.

Whenever the value in my datalist is changed I called oninput event to save the selected option from my datalist.

Now, whenever the oninput event is occured I also want the $index to be passed in the oninput function so that I can use the index value of the elements

How should I get the $index which I used for the div of object which will be repeated into the oninput function.

Comment: It's not very clear what you're asking, don't you just want `this.id` in the handler? Please update your question with a **runnable** [mcve] using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button) (snippets support Angular).

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-repeat="myObject in object track by $index" id="{{ $index }}">
</div>
```

$index starts with 0, so if you want for first object to have index 1, you should set the id to `id="{{ $index +1}}"`